# Replace instances of newlines in entire database

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

In MySQL Workbench I want to replace all instances of newlines with the explicit string "\\n" in my entire database, except where the string already exists. How would I form the query? Thanks.

[edit]

It just occurred to me that it might be easier to dump the database and use Notepad++ to replace the strings. But I was hoping there were a way to do this from within MySQL Workbench itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do this for each table and each column that you want  to do the replacement.  For example:

```
update table set column  = REPLACE(column,'\n','\\n')
```